# Upload File in Chunks/multi-parts with remove button in apex/salesforce

Tags: javascript, file-upload, salesforce, apex, chunks

Upload File in Chunks with JavaScript and save data in salesforce.

I need below functionality :

1. Upload file in Chunks
2. Uploaded file names will be visible below file upload.
3. Ability to remove uploaded files.
4. Customize your Chunk size as per need.
5. Progress Bar indicator for File Upload Progress.

How can I achieve this?